# Can you specify units in a PowerShell property?

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to measure network throughput. The last line of my program is:

`[pscustomobject][ordered]@{Endpoint=$ip; Time=$timeInMilliseconds; Bytes=$totalBytes; Rate=[math]::Round(($totalBytes / $timeInMilliseconds))};`

This returns an output that looks like this:

```
Endpoint       Time   Bytes   Rate
--------       ----   -----   ----
127.0.0.1:9381   15 8388608 559241
```

Is there a way that I can hint to the user what units Time and Rate are in? I think the answer is no, which would explain why commands like `Get-Date` have fields with intuitive names, such as `(Get-Date).Second`.

I do not want to pass an ugly property name that would be difficult to type. For example, `[pscustomobject][ordered]@{Endpoint=$ip; Time=$timeInMilliseconds; Bytes=$totalBytes; "Rate (KB/sec)"=[math]::Round(($totalBytes / $timeInMilliseconds))};` works and produces the desired output

```
Endpoint       Time   Bytes Rate (KB/sec)
--------       ----   ----- -------------
127.0.0.1:9405    9 8388608        932068
```

but now operations like `Select` and `Where-Object` become messy to type. If I were to save the custom object as `$x`, I would have to access the rate field with `$x.'Rate (KB/sec)'`. Again, I think there is not a way to do what I want and I should reconsider my approach.

Comment: As an aside: `[ordered]` is never needed for casting a hashtable to `[pscustomobject]` - it is _implied_ (syntactic sugar).

Comment: simply use a prop name that does NOT include any of the problematic characters like space. [*grin*] ex = `KB_PerSec`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-6) to add an `AliasProperty` called, say, `Rate`, that points to the more messy `Rate (KB/sec)`:

```
$object = [PsCustomObject]@{
    'Rate (KB/Sec)' = "1024"
}


$object | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name Rate -Value 'Rate (KB/sec)'
```

Then users can have the messy version for display and the neater one for scripting:

```
$object.Rate
1024
```

To see an example of alias properties in a common cmdlet, just take a look at the properties for `Get-Process`:

```
Get-Process | Get-Member

Name                       MemberType     Definition
----                       ----------     ----------
Handles                    AliasProperty  Handles = Handlecount
Name                       AliasProperty  Name = ProcessName
NPM                        AliasProperty  NPM = NonpagedSystemMemorySize64
PM                         AliasProperty  PM = PagedMemorySize64
SI                         AliasProperty  SI = SessionId
VM                         AliasProperty  VM = VirtualMemorySize64
WS                         AliasProperty  WS = WorkingSet64
```

Comment: This is a good solution. I end up with fields named "Rate" and also "Rate (KB/sec)", which is mildly ugly when viewing the object, but it directly gives me what I wanted: the ability to both manipulate a one-word variable and separately view its units in a longer description.

Comment: @WilliamJohnHolden, you could use `Format-Table` to display only the fields you want in the output, or you could go full-on and create your own default display with a custom [format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6) file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this new header for display purposes on screen only, you could also simply output the object(s) in a slighlty different way, without altering the original headers:

```
$object = [PsCustomObject]@{
    Endpoint = $ip
    Time     = $timeInMilliseconds
    Bytes    = $totalBytes
    Rate     = [math]::Round(($totalBytes / $timeInMilliseconds))
}

$object | Format-Table -Property Endpoint, Time, Bytes, 
                                 @{Name = 'Rate (KB/sec)'; Expression = { $_.Rate }} -AutoSize
```

will display on console as

> ```
> Endpoint       Time   Bytes Rate (KB/sec)
> --------       ----   ----- -------------
> 127.0.0.1:9405    9 8388608        932068
> ```